# Double equal in statement of dot notation

Tags: javascript, blockchain

Trying to desperately understand the dot notation of the following. From a blockchain basic.

```
self.data = data self.prev_block_hash = previous_block_hash self.calculate_valid_hash()
```

As I'm new to it the data self and previous block hash have not been defined. And the fact there are two equal signs for the same statement. can someone please explain this as I'm guessing this is proof of work part? However, if these are inevitably not equal how will it run?

It also has two colon statements def is_hash_valid(self, hash): return (hash.startswith('0' * 3))  which I thought was for breaking up statements
Many thanks

Comment: please use only a single assignment.

Comment: Considering it as a basic javascript code assignment occurs from left to right, thus if you split above code into different statement it is same as 

   **self.data = previous_block_hash self.calculate_valid_hash()
    self.data = data self.prev_block_hash**

Comment: This code does not seem to work, you are missing either semicolons or newlines. In general, you can chain assignment operators e.g.: `x = y = 2;`, as the assignment operator returns with the assigned value, like: `x = (y = 2);`, where the result of `y=2;` is `2`.

Comment: Many thanks Will breaking it up with brackets work then? self.data = (previous_block_hash self.calculate_valid_hash() self.data = data self.prev_block_hash)